# Working with Scala Option

Tags: scala

I have been changing a lot of my Scala code recently to avoid instantiating variables with `null` and instead using `Option`. For example, I previously had:

```
var cxn: RepositoryConnection = null
cxn = repo.getConnection()
//do something with the connection, then close it
cxn.close()
```

Now, my code looks more like this.

```
var cxn = None : Option[RepositoryConnection]
cxn = Some(repo.getConnection())
//do something with the connection, then close it
```

Now the problem I have is when I want to call a method associated with the RepositoryConnection type. I try:

```
cxn.close()
```

and see this error:

```
value close is not a member of Option[org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryConnection]
```

Now, when I was using `null`, this operation worked just fine, because `cxn` was a `RepositoryConnection` object, not an `Option[RepositoryConnection]`. Is there an easy way to call the `close()` method now that I am using `Option`?

Comment: why can you not use `val cxn = repo.getConnection()` in this case?  The real problem here is using a var and setting it to null/None then later putting a real value in it.  Using `Option` doesn't improve on this much.

Comment: The reason is that due to the design of my code, cxn needs to be a global variable and is not set until later on. In fact the repo object is not yet created when cxn initialized, and I believe this to be necessary due to the technologies that I am working with.

Comment: You don't want option, you want a lazy val by your description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your variable is `Option[Something]`, you can not call `instanceOfSomethingOpt.methodOfInstance()`

Instead do `instanceOfSomethingOpt.map(realInstance => realInstance.methodOfInstance())`

In your case, it'd be

```
cxn.map(realConnection => realConnection.close())

//or to make it shorter
cxn.map(_.close())
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options. (Sorry about the pun.) The most straight forward is probably...

```
cxn.map(_.close())
```

But perhaps you need to do something else if `cxn` is `None`.  Then you could do something like...

```
cxn.fold(logger.reportStatus())(_.close())
```

Comment: `.foreach` is probably a best fit because the OP doesn't seem to care about the `.close` return. Also, instead of `.fold` it can use `.map(stuff).getOrElse(otherStuff)`

Comment: @pedrorijo91, good points. It can be argued that `.getOrElse()` is easier to understand but I tend to prefer `.fold()()` for its conciseness and it's an idiom I think more people should know about. What I really should have included is a [link to the ScalaDocs page](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) where all the various solutions can be found.

Answer (score 1):

You should really give a look at `Option` [api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Option.html).

```
cxn.map(_.close())
```

is one way, in case `close()` returns something you might beed.

```
cxn.foreach(_.close())
```

is another way, if `close()` is not doing much (side-effect).

Answer (score 0):

```
val cxn = Some(repo.getConnection()) 
for (c <- cxn) yield {
   //do something with the connection
   c.close()
}
```

Alternatively you can wrap the getConnection with Either or Try depending on how you want to handle errors see http://blog.xebia.com/try-option-or-either/